# multi-connect to mongodb with php

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to connect to two mongodb servers using php. The one is primary and the other is secondary. It is what I configured:

```
$url = "mongodb://username:password@host1,host2/database";
$mongo = new MongoClient($url);
```

But it did not work in my servers sometimes.

So I tried to configure like that:

```
$url = "mongodb://username:password@host1,host2/?replicaSet=rsName&readPreference=primary";
$mongo = new MongoClient($url);
```

It always did not work.

Does anyone know how to connect?

errors sometimes like:

( ! ) Notice: MongoClient::__construct(): send of 58 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. in C:\tools\wamp\www\frontdoor\public\index.php on line 121

sometimes like:

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: f01.winga.cn:27017: Remote server has closed the connection; Failed to connect to: f02.winga.cn:27017: Remote server has closed the connection' in C:\tools\wamp\www\frontdoor\public\index.php on line 121

( ! ) MongoConnectionException: Failed to connect to: f01.winga.cn:27017: Remote server has closed the connection; Failed to connect to: f02.winga.cn:27017: Remote server has closed the connection in C:\tools\wamp\www\frontdoor\public\index.php on line 121

sometimes like:

( ! ) Notice:MongoClient::_construct():send of 58 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the romote host .in C:\tools\wamp\www\frontdoor\public\index.php on line 121

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: error message added in the end

Comment: Interesting, this is not your config. How is your MongoDB server setup?

Comment: I started mongodb by that:mongod --dbpath /root/MongoData/db0 --replSet "rs0" --keyFile /root/mongodb-keyfile &

Comment: It looks like you can't communicate with those servers. Have you tried pinging them? Connecting to them using the mongo shell? What happens when you try?

Comment: I confirm servers can be connected, because i can connected just a server